# Different UIButton accessibilityLabel depending on whether the button is selected

Tags: ios, uibutton, accessibility, voiceover

I want to have the `accessibilityLabel` of a UIButton to be one value when not `selected`, and one value when `selected`. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Is sounds to me like you are looking for `accessibilityValue`. Have you looked at it?

Comment: Seems like Apple should have a setAccessibilityLabel:forState: method... :/

Comment: @ill_always_be_a_warriors : is your question still topical or have you found out a solution ?

Answer (score 1):

My instinct is to answer: subclass `UIButton` and check `self.selected` within an overridden `accessibilityLabel`.

But you could also take advantage of the fact that `UIControl`s use the `[add/remove]Target` semantics so they can post changes of state to arbitrarily many targets, not just a single delegate. You could create and attach a target that pushes a new `accessbilityLabel` on demand. If you drop down to the runtime level and use `objc_setAssociatedObject` you could associate the helper with the button directly, giving it the same lifetime and avoiding the need for anybody else to keep a reference to it. You should probably just use `UIControlEventAllEvents` rather than trying to write a little implicit table of which events may cause selection to change.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried your first suggestion, but the `accessibilityLabel` method that I overrode isn't being called. FYI, my button is being used as an `accessoryView` in a UITableView. Have you seen this behavior before?

Comment: Have you set `isAccessibilityElement` to `YES` or overridden it always to return `YES`? I think UIKit will walk down the view tree until it finds the largest thing that is an accessibility element so if your table view cell were to say it is an accessibility element then it'd be whatever your cell did that would determine which of its subviews are called (but I'd assume the default implementation acts properly).